# Implementar e realizar operações de conjuntos em listas encadeadas

Tags: java

Alguém poderia me ajudar em implementar uma lista encadeada para realizar operações de conjuntos? Sem utilizar funções nativas do Java, como `ArrayList`.

O algoritmo já gera uma lista encadeada e adiciona novos nós, mas como faço para fazer uma operação como a união?

No `Main`, estou instanciando duas classes, cada uma seria uma lista com valores, mas como chamo uma função de união que receba como parâmetro essas duas listas e como percorre-las simultaneamente? (Sei percorrer uma por vez)

Código - Main

```
public class TrabalhoListas {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ListaDinamica teste = new ListaDinamica();
    ListaDinamica teste2 = new ListaDinamica();
    teste.add(1);
    teste.add(2);
    teste.add(3);
    teste.imprimeLista();
    System.out.println("Segunda lista");
    teste2.add(1);
    teste2.add(6);
    teste2.add(3);
    teste2.imprimeLista();
    System.out.println("Primeira de novo");
    teste.imprimeLista();
}
}
```

--- Lista ---

```
public class Lista {

private int valor;
private Lista prox;

public Lista() {
}

public int getValor() {
    return valor;
}

public void setValor(int valor) {
    this.valor = valor;
}

public Lista getProx() {
    return prox;
}

public void setProx(Lista prox) {
    this.prox = prox;
}
}
```

Lista Dinâmica

```
public class ListaDinamica {

Lista primeiro;
Lista ultimo;
int tamanho = 0;

public ListaDinamica() {
    primeiro = null;
    ultimo = primeiro;
}

public void add(int valor) {
    Lista novo = new Lista();
    novo.setValor(valor);
    tamanho++;
    if (primeiro == null) {
        primeiro = novo;
        ultimo = novo;
        novo.setProx(null);
    } else {
        novo.setProx(primeiro);
        primeiro = novo;
    }
}

public void imprimeLista() {
    Lista atual = primeiro;
    for(int i = 0; i < tamanho; i++){
        System.out.println(atual.getValor());
        atual = atual.getProx();
    }
}

public void uniao(){

}
}
```

Comment: Posta o código do que tentou, mesmo que esteja errado ou incompleto.

Comment: Certo, estarei colocando o Main e o arquivo que estou adicionando.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acho que seria isso, que simplesmente modifica uma `ListaDinamica` concatenando nela uma outra `ListaDinamica`:

```
public void uniao(ListaDinamica outraLista) {
    ultimo.setProx(outraLista.primeiro);
    ultimo = outraLista.ultimo;
    tamanho += outraLista.tamanho;
    removeDuplicatas();
}
```

E para remover duplicatas, você acaba percorrendo a mesma lista duas vezes, uma dentro da outra:

```
private void removeDuplicatas() {
    for (Lista a = primeiro; a != null; a = a.getProx()) {
        for (Lista b = a.getProx(); b != null; b = b.getProx()) {
            if (a.getValor() == b.getValor()) {
                a.setProx(b.getProx());
                tamanho--;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Este algoritmo de remover duplicatas não é lá muito eficiente (tem complexidade de tempo quadrática), mas deve funcionar corretamente e deve servir para os seus propósitos. Bolar um algoritmo eficiente para isso seria bem mais complicado, e neste caso seria melhor usar as classes que o java já lhe dá (como `HashSet` ou `TreeSet`).

Convém também colocar uma chamada a `removeDuplicatas()` no fim do método `add(int)`. Ou então criar um método de busca e usá-lo no método `add(int)` para evitar adicionar um elemento que já exista.

E então, você usa este método no final do método `main`:

```
teste.uniao(teste2);
teste.imprimeLista();
```

Se preferir fazer a união sem modificar nenhuma das duas listas, o melhor então é seguir a abordagem [da minha outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/56135/132).

Comment: Mas neste caso ele concatenaria tudo, entretanto uma união de conjuntos, só agrega valores inexistentes em um conjunto mas que contenham no outro. Ou seja, ele não pode repetir os valores.

Comment: @Natalia Editei a minha resposta para remover as duplicatas.

Comment: agora fiquei na dúvida, sobre matemática mesmo, caso A[1, 2, 1] e B[3, 4, 5] a união não seria C[1, 2, 1, 3, 4, 5]? Ou os números de um conjunto não podem se repetir dentro dele?

Comment: @Natalia Conjuntos, tais como definidos na matemática, não têm elementos repetidos e nem ordem bem definida dos elementos. Exemplo: seja A o conjunto de países da Europa e B o conjunto de países que começam com a letra E. No conjunto que é a união de A e B temos a Espanha, mas não temos duas Espanhas. Também não existe nada dizendo se Espanha vem antes de Eslovênia ou não (a menos que nós venhamos a definir algum critério de ordenação). O mesmo se aplica para a intersecção.

Comment: Entendi e em qual local eu invoco este metodo de união, e como passo para eles os valores das lista A e B?

Comment: @Natalia Resposta editada.

Answer (score 0):

Para fazer a união entre duas listas, basta percorrer a **lista 1** até o último "elemento válido"( **!=null**) e adicionar a **lista 2** como o próximo deste elemento.

```
public static void uniaoLista(Lista l1, Lista l2){

    //Lista auxiliar que vai percorrer a lista 1
    Lista lAux = l1;


    //Percorre a lista l1 até chegar ao ultimo "elemento válido", ou seja, != de null
    while(lAux.getProx()!=null){

        lAux = lAux.getProx();
    }

    //Quando este elemento é achado, dizemos que seu próximo elemento será a lista l2
    lAux.prox = l2;
}
```

Dessa maneira, não teria a necessidade de criar uma classe "Lista Dinâmica", bastaria ter um objeto Lista que recebe a primeira lista e depois fazer a união entre esta lista e uma outra qualquer. Exemplo:

Suponha as listas:

**Lista l1 = 1->2->3->4**

**Lista l2 = 5->6->7->8**

Para realizar a união sem acabar com a lista l1, uma vez que os objetos são passados por referência, faça:

```
...
Lista lUniao = l1.clone();
uniaoLista(lUniao,l2);

//lUniao = 1->2->3->4->5->6->7->8
```

Comment: Certo, mas como passo as listas como parametro? Na Main, minhas listas seriam teste e teste2, como eu mandaria para o método uniaoLista? E também eu preciso fazer uma verificação, por exemplo, caso a l1 = 1->2->3 e a l2 = 2->3->4, apenas o 4 será inserido na nova lista, os valores não se repetem entre os conjuntos.

Comment: Acho que o problema que vocês está tendo é que o método uniaoLista() está dentro de uma classe, então voce precisaria fazer teste1.uniaoLista() ou teste2.uniaoLista(). Faça o seguinte, coloque o método união lista na Main, não esquecendo de colocar o método como estático

Comment: Certo colocando no Main, da para passar por paramêtro, mas surge outro problema, como preciso verificar as igualdades, preciso percorrer a lista, e minhas variaveis globais, como primeiro e ultimo estão na classe ListaDinamica, e para adicionar valores na lista também é realizado na listaDinamica.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode acrescentar um método para descobrir se um elemento existe na `ListaDinamica`:

```
public boolean existe(int elemento) {
    for (Lista a = primeiro; a != null; a = a.getProx()) {
        if (a.getValor() == elemento) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Modificar o método `add(int)` para não deixar adicionar duplicatas:

```
public void add(int valor) {
    if (existe(valor)) return; // Não deixa adicionar duplicatas.
    Lista novo = new Lista();
    novo.setValor(valor);
    tamanho++;
    if (primeiro == null) {
        primeiro = novo;
        ultimo = novo;
        novo.setProx(null);
    } else {
        novo.setProx(primeiro);
        primeiro = novo;
    }
}
```

E na união, é só acrescentar todos os elementos da outra lista:

```
public void uniao(ListaDinamica outraLista) {
    for (Lista a = outraLista.primeiro; a != null; a = a.getProx()) {
        add(a.getValor());
    }
}
```

E então, você usa este método no final do método `main`:

```
teste.uniao(teste2);
teste.imprimeLista();
```

Talvez você não goste do fato do método `uniao` modificar a lista. Se for este o caso, e você quiser na verdade criar uma nova lista sem modificar nenhuma das duas, então faça isso:

```
public ListaDinamica uniao(ListaDinamica outraLista) {
    ListaDinamica novaLista = new ListaDinamica();
    for (Lista a = primeiro; a != null; a = a.getProx()) {
        novaLista.add(a.getValor());
    }
    for (Lista a = outraLista.primeiro; a != null; a = a.getProx()) {
        novaLista.add(a.getValor());
    }
    return novaLista;
}
```

E então no seu método `main`:

```
ListaDinamica teste3 = teste.uniao(teste2);
teste3.imprimeLista();
```

Comment: Certo e onde eu invoco este método, e como passo os valores das listas adicionadas?

Comment: @Natalia Resposta editada.

Comment: Ele não permite atribuir teste.uniao, reporta como incompatibilidade, você teria um outro tipo de contato com o hangout ou algo do genêro? Preciso entender como percorrer estas duas listas simultaneamente para fazer algumas verificações, e tentar solucionar meu problema da união. Claro que se não tiver essa possibilidade eu irei entender.

Comment: @Natalia O primeiro método `uniao` que dei é `void`. Ele modifica a lista `teste` ao invés de criar uma lista nova. O segundo método `uniao` que dei usa a abordagem de criar uma lista nova. As duas abordagens são mutuamente incompatíveis entre si e você provavelmente só vai querer escolher uma delas. A forma como você vai colocá-las no `main` depende da abordagem que você escolher.

Comment: @Natalia Quanto a contato comigo, você pode pegar o meu e-mail na minha página de usuário (é só clicar no link com o meu nome e "scrollar" o quadro à direita até o fim). Mas aqui no StackOverflow há várias pessoas que podem te ajudar, sendo que eu sou apenas um.

Comment: é que você foi muito claro quanto a sua resposta, consegui realizar, entretanto preciso só entender uma questão, irei entrar em contato com você, se você estiver disponivel claro.

Comment: @Natalia Ok. :)

Comment: acabo de enviar um e-mail, e agradeço pela ajuda e pela paciencia tanto de voçê quanto de todos que deram atenção.